# Sum of two numbers from a .txt file (Python2)

Tags: python

I have a question about writing a Python program to have the sum of 2 numbers from a txt file. (This question was from the Australian Informatics Olympiad Training Website)

The Input File is: addin.txt
and the Output File is: addout.txt

Input:
The input file will consist of the two integers a and b separated by a single space. It is guaranteed that 0 <= a, b <= 1,000,000,000.

Output:
The output file should consist of a single integer, the sum of a and b.

Sample Input:
    23 45
Sample Output:
    68

So far, I know how to read and write from txt files but I don't know how it would read the two numbers in the input separately.

Is it possible anyone could show me a program that would fit with this criteria? (Preferable with comments so I can understand it)

Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: Are the Australian Informatics Olympiad about googling and getting others doing things for you?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, guys I realized I needed to add a bit more information.

So far, I know how to read and write from txt files but I don't know how it would read the two numbers in the input separately.

No, this was just a practice question that I couldn't find any help for anywhere else.
Is it possible someone could show me a program that would fit with this criteria? (Preferable with comments so I can understand it)

Comment: place your code in question... so we get idea what have you tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('addin.txt', 'r') as inpt:
    number = inpt.readlines()[0].split(' ')  # split the string to get a list of numbers

with open('addout.txt', 'w') as out:
    # convert number in int, sum them and convert back to a string to write it in the output file
    out.write(str(int(number[0])+int(number[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
addin_df = pd.read_csv('addin.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
addin_df['sum'] = addin_df[0] + addin_df[1]
addin_df['sum'].to_csv('addout.txt', index=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already know how to read from a file, I assume you have a variable `vars` which contain the input from `addin.txt`. You just have to split the string and add them together.

```
>>> elements = vars.split(' ')
>>> sum = int(elements[0]) + int(elements[1])
```

`sum` should now store the result.

Related question on how to convert from String to Integer using Python: [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Quick guide on how to split strings in Python:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm